# Rails routes cached in a variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, lambda, routes

How do i cache a routes in to a variable, with lambda, but how to create it outside of the routes block?

somefile.rb that is loaded before the routes.rb block gets called:

```
x = lambda do
  namespace :test do

    root to: 'application#index'

    get 'page/:page', to: 'pages#show', as: :page

  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  x.call if yep

end
```

Code like this doesn't work because of some DSL class loading error. I don't really understand how the scope works inside of blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass your lambda to the `draw` method directly:

```
# config/routes.rb
conditional_routes = lambda {
  namespace :test do
    root to: 'application#index'
    match 'page/:page' => 'pages#show', as: :page
  end
}

TestApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # default routes
end

TestApp::Application.routes.draw(&conditional_routes) if yep
```

In this example, I'm defining the lambda in the same file (`config/routes.rb`), but you could put it in an initializer or a library file or wherever you like:

```
# config/initializers/conditional_routes.rb
module ConditionalRoutes
  def self.routes
    lambda {
      # ...
    }
  end
end

# config/routes.rb
TestApp::Application.routes.draw(&ConditionalRoutes.routes)
```

Comment: @anxiety Your answer assumes the OP was testing the condition at routing time, not at application load time, which is how I interpreted it.

Answer (score 0):

In your initializer:

```
class Routes
    attr_accessor :routes

    def initialize(routes)
        @routes = routes
    end

    module Helper
        def test_namespace
            Routes.new(self).create_routes
        end
    end

    def self.install!
        ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.send :include, Routes::Helper
    end

    def create_routes
        routes.namespace :test do
            root to: 'application#index'
            get 'page/:page', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
        end
    end
end

Routes.install!
```

In your routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    test_namespace if yep
end
```

I'm REALLY not sure it will work, but it might give you ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a good practice to keep the route declarations explicit *within routes.rb*. The routes.rb file is intended to be the only place you have to look to see how routes are defined.

Also, no need to make a call to `routes.draw` twice.

routes.rb

```
TestApp::Application.routes.draw do

  constraints(Yep) do
    namespace :test do
      root to: 'application#index'
      get 'page/:page', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
    end
  end

end
```

lib/yep.rb

```
class Yep
  def self.matches?(request)
    # if this returns true, your routes block will be drawn
  end
end
```